# Users location (blue dot) keeps turning into red pin

Tags: annotations, mkmapview, mapkit, cllocationmanager, mkpinannotationview

I would like to have the users location as a blue dot while having pins also on the mapview. I would like the pins to have an annotation that has a an info button. 
I can get the blue dot for users location and the enable the pins to have an annotation such as a title an subtitle. However when I go to add the info button to the red pins the users location (blue dot) turns into a red pin.

I can't seem to spot where I'm going wrong. It has something to do with the last function because this is the function that puts a the info button onto the annotation. But it also selects the users current location and turns it into a pin for some reason :(

```
 class GetToTheStart: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!




let myLocMgr = CLLocationManager()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    myLocMgr.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    myLocMgr.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    myLocMgr.startUpdatingLocation()
    myLocMgr.delegate = self




    mapView.delegate = self


  var zoo = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(53.3562, -6.3053)

    var zoopin = MKPointAnnotation()
    zoopin.coordinate = zoo
    zoopin.title = "dublin zoo"
    zoopin.subtitle = "hello this is the zoo"
    mapView.addAnnotation(zoopin)
    }



    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    // get most recient coordinate
    let myCoor = locations[locations.count - 1]

    //get lat & long
    let myLat = myCoor.coordinate.latitude
    let myLong = myCoor.coordinate.longitude
    let myCoor2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: myLat, longitude: myLong)

    //set span
    let myLatDelta = 0.05
    let myLongDelta = 0.05
    let mySpan = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: myLatDelta, longitudeDelta: myLongDelta)

    let myRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: myCoor2D, span: mySpan)

    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true        
    }





    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    let reuseIdentifier = "pin"
    var pin =       mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier) as? MKPinAnnotationView
    if pin == nil {
        pin = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        pin!.pinColor = .Red
        pin!.canShowCallout = true
        pin!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .DetailDisclosure)
    } else {
        pin!.annotation = annotation
    }
    return pin
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**viewForAnnotation** delegate method will be called by all the annotation on the map including **userLocation**.

So you just check and return nil for it as shown below...

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {  
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
    //return nil so map view draws "blue dot" for standard user location
        return nil
    }
    let reuseIdentifier = "pin"
    var pin = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier) as? MKPinAnnotationView
    if pin == nil {
        pin = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        pin!.pinColor = .Red
        pin!.canShowCallout = true
        pin!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .DetailDisclosure)
     } else {
        pin!.annotation = annotation
     }
     return pin
}
```

Comment: With Pleasure...While posting the question maintain some standards at least  for the code part